# Recursion error while sorting a list of numbers without quicksort

Tags: haskell

```
order :: [Int] -> [Int]
order [] = []
order [x] = [x]
order (x:y:xs) = if x>y
then [y] ++ (order (x:xs))
else [x] ++ (order (y:xs))
```

I tried to use this Haskell code to sort a list of numbers, but when I input a list with more than 4 elements it doesn't sort them correctly. I want to keep the code as it compiles but I don't know how to make the recursion work correctly.

Comment: This is one pass of [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). You need to keep calling `order` until the list stops changing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is fine and does exactly what you implemented, but what you implemented does not in fact sort a list.  Let's try it with `[4,3,2]`:

```
order [4,3,2]

order [] = []               -- Nope not an empty list
order [x] = [x]             -- nope not a singleton
order (x:y:xs) = if x>y     -- x=4, y=3, xs =[2]; x >y  is true
then [y] ++ (order (x:xs))  -- this branch [3] ++ (order [4,2])
else [x] ++ (order (y:xs))  -- not this branch
```

So we get to `[3] ++ (order [4,2])`.  Question for you: how does `2` move to the other side of `3`?